# Numpy put array in Nth dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I often end up trying to take a bunch of arrays and putting them in different dimensions as below,

```
x = x.reshape((x.size, 1, 1))
y = y.reshape((1, y.size, 1))
z = z.reshape((1, 1, z.size))

return x + y + z
```

I have two problems, I would like to do something like,

```
x = x.todim(0)
y = y.todim(1)
z = z.todim(2)
```

And achieve the same as above.

Also, I would like to do "tensor products" with different operators and have it be lazy evaluated because doing what I am doing often exploded the memory usage. But I do have a good reason for doing these kinds of things ... my insanity is justifiable.

EDIT:

Here is code I wrote to do it, but a built in would be nice is such exists

```
def todim(a, ndims, axis=0):
    nshape = [a.shape[i-axis]
              if i >= axis and (i-axis) < len(a.shape)
              else 1
              for i in range(ndims)]
    return a.reshape(tuple(nshape))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you are doing something similar to `np.ix_`.

```
In [899]: x,y,z=np.ix_(np.arange(3),np.arange(4),np.arange(5))
In [900]: x.shape,y.shape,z.shape
Out[900]: ((3, 1, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 1, 5))
```

`numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` has this and other indexing functions and classes.

A function like your `todim` could be:

```
 def todim(x,n,i):
    ind = [1]*n
    ind[i]=x.shape[0]
    return x.reshape(ind)
```

I'm not trying to make it a array method.  A standalone function is easier.  I also need to define the `n`, the target number of dimensions.  `np.ix_` does something like this.

---

To `todim` that you added (while I wrote my answer) is similar, but lets `x` have something other than 1d.

`np.r_` takes an intial string argument that might allow similar specification.

```
x,y,z = np.r_['0,3,0',np.arange(3)], np.r_['0,3,1',np.arange(4)], np.r_['0,3,2',np.arange(5)]
```

produces the same 3 arrays as my initial `ix_`.  It takes a string input, but you could easily insert numbers:

```
np.r_['0,%s,%s'%(3,1), np.arange(4)]
```